# Как поместить меню ToolStrip в заголовок окна? Как в Visual Studio 2019 сделано

Tags: c#, winforms

В Visual Studio 2019 главное меню переехало в строку, которая исторически называется термином "заголовок окна". Как мне на WinForms сделать так же?

Visual Studio:
[image: скриншот главного меню Visual Studio 2019 левая часть]

[image: скриншот главного меню Visual Studio 2019 правая часть]

Кажется, я уже понял как это сделано. Это не заголовок вовсе, а его имитация. Выдают не родные кнопки управления окна. А вот в Google Chrome кнопки родные..

Google Chrome:

[image: скриншот "заголовка окна" Google Chrome правая часть]

А значит, там использован другой подход к решению этого вопроса. Впрочем, там и платформа разработки, наверняка не [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)

И всё-таки как реализовать меню-заголовок тем или иным способом?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нарисуем форму, бросим панель `Dock = Top`. На неё два ToolStripEx.

```
/// <summary>
/// Вылечена часть глюков ToolStrip с фокусом
/// </summary>
public class ToolStripEx : ToolStrip
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == WinApi.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE &&
            m.Result == (IntPtr)WinApi.MA_ACTIVATEANDEAT)
        {
            m.Result = (IntPtr)WinApi.MA_ACTIVATE;
        }            
    }
}
```

Настройка свойств:

левое `GripStyle = Hidden, RenderMode = System, Dock = Fill`

правое `GripStyle = Hidden, RenderMode = System, Dock = Fill, LayoutStyle = Flow`

На левом разместим:

- кнопку имитирующую системное меню окна,
- кнопки самого меню, которое нас интересовало,
- ToolStripLabel, который будет играть роль заголовка окна

На правом кидаем кнопки, которые будут имитировать штатный ControlBox.
Получилось вот так.

[image: скриншот формы приложения в дизайн-тайм]
[image: скриншот "Структуры документа" для формы]

Теперь собственно нужно убрать заголовок, а имитатору обеспечить схожее поведение.

Самое простое -- это нажатия ControlBox и двойной клик по "заголовку-имитатору".

```
private void toolStripTitle_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized ?
                   FormWindowState.Normal
                   : FormWindowState.Maximized;
    UpdateControlBox();
}

private void toolStripButtonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Close();
}

private void toolStripButtonMaximize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    UpdateControlBox();
}

private void toolStripButtonMinimize_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void toolStripButtonRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    UpdateControlBox();
}
private void UpdateControlBox()
{
    toolStripButtonMaximize.Visible = WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized;
    toolStripButtonRestore.Visible = WindowState != FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Для того, чтобы скрыть родной заголовок, есть три или четыре способа. Но все, кроме одного, страдают недостатками: мы теряем возможность отображать текст в TaskBar, или теряем возможность вызывать "системное меню окна".

Мой способ основан на следующем: в дизайнере мы сохраняем стандартный вид окна, затем в обработчике Form.Load захватываем Handle "системное меню окна", и только потом с помощью `SetWindowLongPtr` ликвидируем штатный заголовок.

```
private IntPtr sysMenuHandle;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Захватываем меню
    sysMenuHandle = WinApi.GetSystemMenu(this.Handle, false);

    //Ликвидируем штатный заголовок
    int style = WinApi.GetWindowLongPtr(this.Handle, WinApi.GWL_STYLE).ToInt32();
    WinApi.SetWindowLongPtr(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), WinApi.GWL_STYLE,
        (IntPtr)(style & ~WinApi.WS_CAPTION));

    //Сворачиваем окно и возвращаем как-было
    //Это костыль, чтобы нормально перерисовалось окно после предыдущей операции
    //Не помешало бы найти менее корявый способ
    var winstate = this.WindowState; 
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    this.WindowState = winstate;

    //Обновляем внешний вид ControlBox
    UpdateControlBox();            
}
```

Теперь мы сможем вызывать "системное меню окна"

```
private void toolStripTitle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd = this.Handle;
        WinApi.GetWindowRect(hWnd, out WinApi.RECT pos);                
        int cmd = WinApi.TrackPopupMenu(sysMenuHandle, 0x100,  
            this.Left + e.X, this.Top + e.Y, 0, hWnd, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (cmd > 0) WinApi.SendMessage(hWnd, 0x112, (IntPtr)cmd, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}

private void toolStripIcon_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    toolStripTitle_MouseDown(sender, e);
}
```

Ещё осталось вернуть возможность таскать окно за заголовок

```
public partial class Form1 : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    private HashSet<Control> controlsToMove = new HashSet<Control>();        

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        controlsToMove.Add(this.toolStripTitle);           
    }
    
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {            
        if (m.Msg == WinApi.WM_LBUTTONDOWN &&
             controlsToMove.Contains(Control.FromHandle(m.HWnd)))
        {                
            WinApi.SendMessage(this.Handle, WinApi.WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN,
                                (IntPtr)WinApi.HT_CAPTION, (IntPtr)0);                
        }
        return false;
    }
```

---

Некоторые ответы использованные в данном решении:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23966253/moving-form-without-title-bar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472301/toolstrip-sometimes-not-responding-to-a-mouse-click
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245498/application-title-in-taskbar-but-not-titlebar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825352/how-to-open-window-system-menu-on-right-click
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695154/winapi-getsystemmenu-without-ws-sysmenu-in-style

Answer (score 6):

Скорее всего, Chrome использует способ с DWM API, описанный здесь: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe). Суть в том, чтобы расширить клиентскую область окна на ее рамку через DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea и допилить обработку сообщений так, чтобы стандартные кнопки свернуть-закрыть при этом продолжали работать. В WinForms это можно применить как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {      
        //размеры отступов клиентской области
        const int TOPEXTENDWIDTH = 1;
        const int BOTTOMEXTENDWIDTH = 30;
        const int LEFTEXTENDWIDTH = 1;
        const int RIGHTEXTENDWIDTH = 1;

        //WinAPI
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MARGINS
        {
            public int cxLeftWidth;
            public int cxRightWidth;
            public int cyBottomHeight;
            public int cyTopHeight;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left, top, right, bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hwnd, ref MARGINS margins);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool AdjustWindowRectEx(ref RECT lpRect, uint dwStyle,
        bool bMenu, uint dwExStyle);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        static extern bool DwmDefWindowProc(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref IntPtr plResult);

        static int GET_X_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short loword = (short)((ulong)lp & 0xffff);
            return loword;
        }

        static int GET_Y_LPARAM(IntPtr lp)
        {
            short hiword = (short)((((ulong)lp)>>16) & 0xffff);
            return hiword;
        }

        const uint WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083;
        const uint WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;

        const uint WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000;
        const uint WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;
        const uint WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000;
        const uint WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;
        const uint WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
        const uint WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000;
        const uint WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU |
              WS_THICKFRAME |  WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

        const uint HTTOPLEFT = 13;
        const uint HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
        const uint HTTOP = 12;
        const uint HTCAPTION = 2;
        const uint HTLEFT = 10;
        const uint HTNOWHERE = 0;
        const uint HTRIGHT = 11;
        const uint HTBOTTOM = 15;
        const uint HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16;
        const uint HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

        //обработка координат мыши для неклиентской области
        static IntPtr HitTestNCA(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // Get the point coordinates for the hit test.
            var ptMouse = new Point(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));

            // Get the window rectangle.
            RECT rcWindow;
            GetWindowRect(hWnd, out rcWindow);

            // Get the frame rectangle, adjusted for the style without a caption.
            RECT rcFrame = new RECT();
            AdjustWindowRectEx(ref rcFrame, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_CAPTION, false, 0);

            // Determine if the hit test is for resizing. Default middle (1,1).
            ushort uRow = 1;
            ushort uCol = 1;
            bool fOnResizeBorder = false;

            // Determine if the point is at the top or bottom of the window.
            if (ptMouse.Y >= rcWindow.top && ptMouse.Y < rcWindow.top + BOTTOMEXTENDWIDTH)
            {
                fOnResizeBorder = (ptMouse.Y < (rcWindow.top - rcFrame.top));
                uRow = 0;
            }
            else if (ptMouse.Y < rcWindow.bottom && ptMouse.Y >= rcWindow.bottom - TOPEXTENDWIDTH)
            {
                uRow = 2;
            }

            // Determine if the point is at the left or right of the window.
            if (ptMouse.X >= rcWindow.left && ptMouse.X < rcWindow.left + LEFTEXTENDWIDTH)
            {
                uCol = 0; // left side
            }
            else if (ptMouse.X < rcWindow.right && ptMouse.X >= rcWindow.right - RIGHTEXTENDWIDTH)
            {
                uCol = 2; // right side
            }

            // Hit test (HTTOPLEFT, ... HTBOTTOMRIGHT)
            IntPtr[,] hitTests = new IntPtr[,]
            {
                { (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT, fOnResizeBorder? (IntPtr)HTTOP : (IntPtr)HTCAPTION, (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT },
                { (IntPtr)HTLEFT,  (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE, (IntPtr)HTRIGHT},
                { (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT, (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM, (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT },
            };

            return hitTests[uRow, uCol];
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in menuStrip1.Items)
            {
                item.Paint += Item_Paint;
            }
        }

        private void Item_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (item == null) return;

            //для элементов, которые лежат на бывшей рамке окна, нужна нестандартная отрисовка
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, 2, 2, item.Width - 4,item.Height - 4);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Text, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, SystemBrushes.ControlText, 2, 2);
        }

        //при первой активации окна расширим клиентскую область на рамку окна
        bool dwminit = false;
        private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dwminit == false)
            {
                // Extend the frame into the client area.
                MARGINS margins = new MARGINS();

                margins.cxLeftWidth = LEFTEXTENDWIDTH;
                margins.cxRightWidth = RIGHTEXTENDWIDTH;
                margins.cyBottomHeight = BOTTOMEXTENDWIDTH;
                margins.cyTopHeight = TOPEXTENDWIDTH;

                int hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(this.Handle, ref margins);
                dwminit = true;

                if (hr != 0)
                {
                    throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            bool fCallDWP = true;
            IntPtr lRet = IntPtr.Zero;
            fCallDWP = !DwmDefWindowProc(m.HWnd, m.Msg, m.WParam, m.LParam, ref lRet);

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCCALCSIZE)
            {
                if (m.WParam != (IntPtr)0)
                {
                    //убираем страндартную рамку
                    lRet = IntPtr.Zero;                    
                    fCallDWP = false;
                }
            }

            if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST && lRet==IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //обработка нажатий мыши
                lRet = HitTestNCA(m.HWnd, m.WParam, m.LParam);

                if (lRet != (IntPtr)HTNOWHERE)
                {
                    fCallDWP = false;
                }
            }

            m.Result = lRet;

            //если сообщение не обработано, передаем в базовый класс
            if (fCallDWP) base.WndProc(ref m);
        }             

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //это нужно, чтобы были видны рамка и кнопки свернуть-закрыть в Windows 10, 
            //так как рамку система принудительно заливает белым

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, this.Width, BOTTOMEXTENDWIDTH);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, this.Width - RIGHTEXTENDWIDTH, 0, RIGHTEXTENDWIDTH, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, LEFTEXTENDWIDTH, this.Height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, this.Height- TOPEXTENDWIDTH, this.Width, TOPEXTENDWIDTH);
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //необходимо для корректной перерисовки рамки при изменении размера
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        //другие обработчики событий...        
    }
}
```

Вид в Form Designer:

[image: designer]

Вид при запуске:

[image: runtime]

Естественно, это довольно грубый пример, заточенный под стандартную тему Windows 10 - чтобы это нормально работало независимо от темы, желательно не задавать константные отступы, а получать параметры окна через [GetSystemMetrics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics). Но я думаю, идея понятна.

На практике этот способ для WinForms, я думаю, не очень удобен, из-за необходимости рисовать вручную все элементы, которые попадают в бывшую неклиентскую область.

**Внимание:** На Vista/7 этот способ будет работать только с включенным DWM Composition. На предыдущих версиях - вообще не будет.

Comment: Что-то не удалось повторить на Windows 7. Вид при запуске совсем не такой, как у вас. В винде в  "параметрах быстродействия"  все галки включены. В добавок пришлось перезагружать компьютер из-за возникших глюков с Вводом, хотя может быть совпадение..

Comment: @4per покажите скриншот, как форма отображается в Windows 7

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBYcO.png

Comment: @4per Странно, у меня вот так на Win7: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWbQA.png - не очень красиво, но приемлемо. У вас у формы какие-то свойства изменены на нестандартные? Если пересоздать форму с нуля, то же самое?

Comment: уупс.. всё работает, как у вас. Я сдуру забыл привязать обработчики событий.